# Domain fronting proxy in Java, won't get "pull method" proxy to work

Tags: java, sockets, proxy

I'm currently working on a project that uses a technique called "domain fronting". In short: it send internet traffic to a CDN (in this case Google) over an encrypted connection, and the CDN then passes back this info to the proxy. This way you can circumvent censorship (as long a the CDN isn't blocked), because the real destination is unknown to a observer. (To read more about domain fronting, here is the original [paper](https://www.bamsoftware.com/papers/fronting.pdf)) A number of applications like Signal and Tor already use this technique, but there isn't a general use proxy that just proxies a tcp socket through Google to the other end. I decided to go work on that and it's almost finished: the HTTP encoding part and the code at Google's servers is working. The only problem is the real proxying part.
This is the structure of the proxy:
source-->client proxy-->[Google]-->server proxy-->destination

The difference with a general proxy is that HTTP is a request based protocol and thus can't do the asynchronous things normal proxies do. My setup is to make a request from the client once in 100ms to the server sending the bytes the client received to the server. The server reads the bytes from the destination and sends them back to the client. Than the server and client both write their received bytes to the original sockets and another roundtrip starts in 100ms.

Here is my code to this point (I only pasted the relevant part, this code is not domain fronting yet):
Client:

```
try {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8082);
        System.out.println("client proxy is listening for connections");
        Socket source = serverSocket.accept();
        BufferedReader sourceIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(source.getInputStream()));
        PrintWriter sourceOut = new PrintWriter(source.getOutputStream(), false);
        while(true) {
            Socket server = new Socket("localhost", 8081);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(server.getInputStream()));
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(server.getOutputStream(), false);

            //read what the source has for the server
            System.out.println("start reading source socket");
            System.out.println("available: " + source.getInputStream().available());
            char[] buffer = new char[15000];
            int bytesRead = 0;
            if(source.getInputStream().available() != 0) {
                bytesRead = sourceIn.read(buffer);
                byte[] bytesToSend = new byte[bytesRead];
                bytesToSend = Arrays.copyOfRange(new String(buffer).getBytes(), 0, bytesRead);
                out.print((byte) 1);
                out.print(bytesToSend);
                out.flush();
                System.out.println("Sent to server: " + new String(bytesToSend) + " bytesRead: " + bytesRead);
            } else {
                out.print((byte) 0);
                out.flush();
                System.out.println("Sent to server: nothing");
            }

            //read what the server has for the source
            buffer = new char[15000];
            bytesRead = 0;
            while((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) == -1) {
                System.out.println("didn't receive any bytes from server");
                Thread.sleep(20);
            }
            byte[] bytesToSend = Arrays.copyOfRange(new String(buffer).getBytes(), 0, bytesRead);
            if(bytesToSend[0] == '1') {
                sourceOut.print(bytesToSend);
                sourceOut.flush();
                System.out.println("Sent to source: " + new String(bytesToSend));
            } else {
                System.out.println("Server has nothing for source; bytesToSend: " + new String(bytesToSend));
            }

            in.close();
            out.close();
            server.close();
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Server:

```
try {
            Socket destination = new Socket("192.168.0.150", 22);
            BufferedReader destinationIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(destination.getInputStream()));
            PrintWriter destinationOut = new PrintWriter(destination.getOutputStream(), false);
            ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(8081);
            while(true) {
                Socket clientSocket = server.accept();
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), false);
                System.out.println("received new connection from client");

                //read what client has for destination
                char[] buffer = new char[15000];
                int bytesRead = 0;
                while((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) == -1) {
                    System.out.println("didn't receive any bytes from client");
                    Thread.sleep(20);
                }
                byte[] bytesToSend = Arrays.copyOfRange(new String(buffer).getBytes(), 0, bytesRead);
                if(bytesToSend[0] == (byte) 1) {
                    destinationOut.print(bytesToSend);
                    destinationOut.flush();
                    System.out.println("Sent to destination: " + new String(bytesToSend));
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Client has nothing for destination");
                }

                //read what distination has for client
                System.out.println("start reading destination socket");
                System.out.println("available: " + destination.getInputStream().available());
                buffer = new char[15000];
                if(destination.getInputStream().available() != 0) {
                    bytesRead = destinationIn.read(buffer);
                    bytesToSend = new byte[bytesRead];
                    bytesToSend = Arrays.copyOfRange(new String(buffer).getBytes(), 0, bytesRead);
                    out.print("1");
                    out.print(new String(bytesToSend));
                    out.flush();
                    System.out.println("Sent to client: " + new String(bytesToSend) + " bytesRead: " + bytesRead);
                } else {
                    out.print((byte) 0);
                    out.flush();
                    System.out.println("Sent to client: nothing");
                }
                out.close();
                in.close();
                clientSocket.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

When I run this code to connect to a SSH server, the SSH client freezes and it seems like the proxy server doesn't respond to the proxy client anymore.

I really hope someone can help me with this, if you need extra info, just let me know! :)